# Return the string after a certain number of words in Django

Tags: django-templates

I don't know how to explain what I want to do. This example can help.

I have a text:
"My name is Stefano and I'm from Uruguay."

And I want to show:
"My name is Stefano...
...and I'm from Uruguay"

I'm using truncatewords for the first line.

Comment: Some info please. What's criteria you're using to split string? Any number of words? Are you trying to insert `"\n..."` (based on your example) after certain number of words or you expect something else? Clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'm using {% texto|truncatewords:4 %} to show "My name is Stefano...", and I want to show "...and I'm from Uruguay" with something similar to truncatewords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: {{ my_text.split|slice:'4:'|join:' ' }}